# how to get next postion for same class with jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get next position for same class with jquery,

I am trying this code but it's not working on next click

```
var directiveScrollTop= $(".site_section").next().position().top;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.eq(1)` in place of `.next()`?

Comment: yes but it's working same like next(). i have all sections on single page:
<section class="myclass"></section>
<section class="myclass"></section>
<section class="myclass"></section>

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. Post the rest of your code.

Comment: $(".slide-down").on("click", function (e){
   var directiveScrollTop = $("#contact").height();  e.preventDefault(); 
   
   if($(window).scrollTop() != ($(document).height() - $("#contact").height())){
    
    var directiveScrollTop= $(".site_section").eq(1).position().top;
    
    console.log(directiveScrollTop);
    
    $(this).removeClass("slide-up").addClass("slide-down");
    $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop:directiveScrollTop}, 1500);
   }
   else{
    $(this).removeClass("slide-down").addClass("slide-up");
    $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1500);
   } 
 
});

Comment: Try using `$(this).closest('.site_section')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on some element and needs to find the next element with class `site_section`:

```
$(this).nextAll(".site_section")
```

So your code should be:

```
var directiveScrollTop= $(this).nextAll(".site_section").position().top;
```

They need to be at the same depth in the DOM though.